# Moles and System.Threading.ManualResetEvent

Tags: .net, moles

We've had some success using Moles in unit tests for several classes which rely heavily on framework objects which cannot be mocked. We've run into a bit of a roadblock with `System.Threading.ManualResetEvent` and `System.Threading.AutoResetEvent` however, which seem to resist Moles for inexplicable reasons. More specifically, `System.Threading.Moles.MManualResetEvent.AllInstances.` provides no methods for which we could set a delegate. `System.Threading.Thread`, `System.Threading.Mutex` and `System.Threading.ManualResetEventSlim` are all Moles-capable, which would seem to indicate that support *should* be available; does anyone know why it is not, or what we are doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is not really answering the question, but you might want to use the following, popular technique for mocking "unmockable" objects: Define an interface, say `IManualResetEvent`, that contains the necessary methods and properties from `ManualResetEvent`, and an adapter class, `ManualResetEventAdapter`, that implements `IManualResetEvent` and wraps an actual `ManualResetEvent`. Then, use `IManualResetEvent` everywhere in your application. This is particularily convenient if you already are using a dependency injection framework, as you could specify that a `ManualResetEventAdapter` should always be passed to classes that require an `IManualResetEvent`.

Comment: Agreed. You should use a stub, for cases like this. The problem is that these components are outside the control of your application, and therefore can not be detoured through the Moles wrapper assembly.  They can't be detoured, because these are processes that are handled by the operating or other system, such as IIS.